# Document Library with incoming email enabled - difference between an appointment or regular e-mail

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-foundation, email, incoming-email

I would like to have a document library created with incoming mail turned on.  I've set this up, it is working fine.  One thing I would like to do is figure out a way to categorize the incoming email (.EML file) as to whether it is an e-mail or an appointment?  I understand an appointment is really just an e-mail but I was wondering if anyone can hint at a way to determine the difference.  I've scanned over the email headers between the two but nothing is standing out.  I know in the e-mail message, there is some typical text that is sent but I don't believe a workflow can open a EML file and read out the text to a variable.

My workaround will be to create a seperate document library and seperate e-mail address for meeting requests but I'd like to only have one e-mail address for ease of use for my end users.

Answer (score 1):

If you considering email for meeting, why not already use calendars in SharePoint that actually could receive events by email, and leave documents in libraries. 
See here how to setup http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-and-update-a-sharepoint-calendar-HA010081987.aspx#BM6

Answer (score 0):

We just found it was easier to create two document libraries, one specifically for meetings and then create a page that can view both libraries at the same time.